# dplyr::select function clashes with MASS::select

Tags: r, dplyr

If I load the `MASS` package:

```
library(MASS)
```

then load try to run `dplyr::select`, I get a error:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %.%
select(mpg)

# Error in select(`__prev`, mpg) : unused argument (mpg)
```

How can I use `dplyr::select` with the `MASS` package loaded?

Comment: You can use it as you just wrote: `dplyr::select(mpg)`

Comment: As of today 03.12.2019, five years later it's still not fixed, I just had the exact same issue.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

As Pascal said, the following works

```
require(MASS)
require(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
   dplyr::select(mpg)
```

Comment: If you are sure you are going to load MASS and dplyr together very often and use 'select' a lot, you could do reassign the function:  select <- dplyr::select    which could help save typing 'dplyr::' repeatedly

Comment: I know this is old but anyway. Just encountered the same problem. And apparently MASS is imported (among others) by ggplot2 so I guess many are likely to use them together. Although I believe I've been using ggplot2 and dplyr without problems before...

Comment: I have a similar problem. However, what is weird is that this problem did not occur until today, and I did not really change my code. I only plugged the section causing the error into an `if(x == x) { ... }` condition. Any ideas why this error suddenly appears, where previously there was no problem?

Comment: @deca, I don't have any idea, you might like to ask that as a separate question.

Comment: also clashes with package  `drc`     The workaround is to use `dplyr:select`, as stated above

Answer (score 20):

This happens to me more frequently than I should admit. dplyr clashes with `MASS::select`, `plyr::summarise` and `stats::filter` among other things, especially when loading packages which load one of those libraries via library (they shouldn't, but some still do) or when you load dplyr in your `.Rprofile` (don't!). And it can lead to pretty obscure problems, not always an error message, especially conflicts with `plyr`.

I only recently learned about the `conflicts()` function. It's useful, but "over-reports" conflicts when two packages have identical functions, e.g. tidyr::`%>%` and dplyr::`%>%`.

So I wrote [a function](https://github.com/rubenarslan/rcamisc/blob/master/R/sanity.R#L14) to tell me if I'm going mad or whether there's actually a conflict causing the current bug. It not only checks for conflicts, it checks whether a certain desired package is the one "on top" and whether the function's bodies actually differ.

It does this for dplyr by default, but you can specify another package using the `want_package` parameter. For example, I often get tripped up by `recode` and `alpha`, which are reused in many packages.

Usage is simply: `amigoingmad()`.

By default, it will also automatically "fix" things if dplyr is not "on top", using the following commands:

```
detach("package:dplyr", character.only = TRUE)
library("dplyr", character.only = TRUE)
```

Note that the function will report if a user-specified function is blocking dplyr, but does not fix this automatically for safety's sake (just remove the function in that case).

As of yet, this solution hasn't caused any problems to me. Of course I wouldn't advocate using this in production code, but when you're debugging an `.Rmd`-file and may have messed up the load order by accident it's a quick way to find out.

If you want this in a package:

```
devtools::install_github("rubenarslan/rcamisc")
```

Comment: Beautiful.  I thought I was going mad.

Comment: Could you update this answer, I think the functions you refer to are not in the repo anymore

Comment: @saQuist thanks, I moved it into another package. links fixed.

Answer (score 16):

If you load **first** the `MASS` library and **second** the `dplyr` one

```
library (MASS)
library (dplyr)
```

then the first version of the `select` function in your session `searchpaths ()` will be the one in the `dplyr` library.

Hence

```
select(mtcars, mpg)
```

will work as

```
dplyr::select(mtcars, mpg)
```

Comment: +1 for the hint to `searchpaths()` to self-check. I found out that `library(tidyverse)` loads MASS before dplyr - this causes the frequent error! So the workaround is to explicitly load MASS before tidyverse like `library(MASS); library (tidyverse)`

Answer (score 14):

The other solutions listed here may solve your immediate issue but fail in a critical way: they can't tell you about conflicts that are *unknown* in advance. For example, I just updated some older code and discovered that three packages I was using each have a `summarize` command.

The elegant solution is to load the `conflicted` package in every session / script because it:

- generates informative error messages whenever namespace conflicts arise
- offers an explicit function `conflict_prefer()` to assign namespace priority
- doesn't require the more cumbersome `package::function()` syntax

See example code below partly from https://github.com/r-lib/conflicted

```
# install package
install.packages("conflicted")

# example of how to start load packages at start of your script
library(dplyr)

library(conflicted)
conflict_prefer("select", "dplyr")
conflict_prefer("filter", "dplyr")
```

Below, an example as if you ran `library(conflicted)` at start but did not specify which package gets priority for `filter`:

```
# WITHOUT conflict_prefer("filter", "dplyr")
# example of informative error message

filter(mtcars, cyl == 8)

#> Error: [conflicted] `filter` found in 2 packages.
#> Either pick the one you want with `::` 
#> * dplyr::filter
#> * stats::filter
#> Or declare a preference with `conflicted_prefer()`
#> * conflict_prefer("filter", "dplyr")
#> * conflict_prefer("filter", "stats")
```

Below, an example with `library(conflicted)` and `conflict_prefer("filter", "dplyr")`:

```
# WITH conflict_prefer("filter", "dplyr") as suggested at top
# R knows to assign priority 

library(conflicted)
conflict_prefer("filter", "dplyr")

filter(mtcars, cyl == 8) %>% head(2)
#    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.44 17.02  0  0    3    2
# 2 14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.57 15.84  0  0    3    4
```

Answer (score 9):

As with KFB's comment above, one straightforward solution I've found is to:

1. load your packages
2. don't worry about order (which can be hard with dependencies)
3. assign priority to whichever package you'd prefer "own" the namespace:

```
select <- dplyr::select

filter <- dplyr::filter
```

For example, see how the `environment: namespace` changes below:

```
library(MASS)
select

  function (obj) 
  UseMethod("select")
  <bytecode: 0x7fbe822811b8>
  <environment: namespace:MASS>  # from MASS::select() <---------

select <- dplyr::select
select

  function (.data, ...) 
  {
      UseMethod("select")
  }
  <bytecode: 0x7fbe7c4a2f08>
  <environment: namespace:dplyr> # now dplyr::select() <---------
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying many alternatives, what worked for me was removing MASS and installing it again.