# Select statement error : unused argument

Tags: r, dplyr

The line of code below from the `dplyr` package is super simple.  And yet, its giving me an error.  I'm just trying to practice using the package and want to select a single column, `cyl`, from the data frame `mtcars`.  What's going on here? Any ideas?

```
> select(mtcars, cyl)
```

> Error in select(mtcars, cyl) : unused argument (cyl)

Comment: works for me : `select(mtcars, cyl)`. Alternatively, try `mtcars %>% select(cyl)` should give you the same result.

Comment: can you post your sessionInfo()?

Comment: Or most probably you are facing this issue [dplyr::select function clashes with MASS::select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24202120/dplyrselect-function-clashes-with-massselect) so maybe use `dplyr::select(mtcars, cyl)`.

Comment: yea - that's why I was wondering about the sessionInfo()

Answer (score 6):

Came across the same error. Could not figure out what it was. Out of desperation I installed dplyr again and suddenly it worked...

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. It came out that i have not imported dplyr before calling the select method.

Comment: That will give the error message - Could not find function "select". I experienced the exact same problem, and as suggested reinstalled dplyr. After that, it worked. Mysterious. Must be the R ghost.

Comment: It's because another package is using another "Select" function.