# unnest_tokens() in R creates word column but can't select the word column in dplyr commands

Tags: r, dplyr, nlp, tidytext

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3vhP.png)

When I use the unnest_tokens() command it creates a column called word, as you can see I add colnames() after the pipe function after unnesting and it returns word as a column.

When I save it as a dataframe the column has no name and I have to rename that column.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here 
[dplyr::select function clashes with MASS::select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24202120/dplyrselect-function-clashes-with-massselect)

This happens more than I would like it to. I think we should have better error messaging if we can determine user installed MASS in their R session?

Using dplyr::select worked.

Comment: You might check out the **conflicted** package, since this is a problem with both `select()` and `lag()`: https://github.com/r-lib/conflicted I have code to choose my preferred `select()` and `lag()` in my .Rprofile file, and then I namespace if I want the other one.