# showing estimate value in the forest plot from ZINB model

Tags: r, ggplot2, stat

This question is a follow up question to [Overlay of forest plot from ZINB model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74887877/overlay-of-forest-plot-from-zinb-model/74893652?noredirect=1#comment132395408_74893652). I need help in displaying the estimated value in the forest plot from ZINB model indicated in the picture below

```r
library(sjPlot)
library(sjlabelled)
library(sjmisc)
library(ggplot2)
library(MASS)
library(pscl)
library(boot)

library(broom)
library(poissonreg)
library(tidyverse) ## purrr::map_dfr, ggplot ...
theme_set(theme_bw())
library(colorspace)



zinb_all_uni <- zeroinfl(ivdays~age,
                         link="logit",
                         dist = "negbin",
                         data=caterpillor)



summary(zinb_all_uni)
plot_model(zinb_all_uni, type="est")


zinb_full_adj <- zeroinfl(ivdays~age+sex+edu,
                          link="logit",
                          dist = "negbin",
                          data=caterpillor)

summary(zinb_full_adj)
plot_model(zinb_full_adj, type="est", terms = c("count_ageb", "count_agec", "zero_ageb", "zero_agec"))

############ second model#######


Zinb_uni_sub <- zeroinfl(ivdays~age,
                         link="logit",
                         dist = "negbin",
                         data=subset(caterpillor, country=="eng"))



summary(Zinb_uni_sub)
plot_model(Zinb_uni_sub, type="est")



zinb_adj_sub <- zeroinfl(ivdays~age+sex+edu,
                         link="logit",
                         dist = "negbin",
                         data=subset(caterpillor, country=="eng"))

summary(zinb_adj_sub)

plot_model(zinb_adj_sub, type="est", terms = c("count_ageb", "count_agec", "zero_ageb", "zero_agec"))



mod_list <- list(all_uni = zinb_all_uni, uni_sub = Zinb_uni_sub)


tidy(zinb_all_uni, type = "all")

coefs <- (mod_list
          |> map_dfr(tidy, type = "all",
                     .id = "model")
          ## construct CIs
          |> mutate(conf.low  = qnorm(0.025, estimate, std.error),
                    conf.high = qnorm(0.975, estimate, std.error))
          |> filter(term != "(Intercept)")  ## usually don't want this
          ## cosmetic (strip results down to the components we actually need)
          |> dplyr::select(model, term, type, estimate, conf.low, conf.high)
          ## back-transform
          |> mutate(across(c(estimate, conf.low, conf.high), exp))
          |> filter(stringr::str_detect(term, "^age"))
)

ggplot(coefs, aes(x = estimate, y = term, colour = model)) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(xmin = conf.low, xmax = conf.high),
                  position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  ## separate count-ratio and odds-ratio (conditional/zero) plots
  facet_wrap(~type, scale = "free") +
  scale_color_discrete_qualitative()+ ## cosmetic
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1, lty = 1, color = "yellow", size = 1.5)+
  labs(x = "Incidence rate ratio: #IV days", y= "age")
```

Here is the plots. I would like to display the estimated values circled below:
[image]

[image]

The following is the data:

```
caterpillor=structure(list(id = 1:100,
                           age = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                             2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                             1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
                                             2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
                                             3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                             2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
                                           .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"),
                           sex = structure(c(2L, 
                                             1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                             1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                             1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                             2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 1L, 1L),
                                           .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"),
                           country = structure(c(1L, 
                                                 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
                                                 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                 2L, 2L, 2L),
                                               .Label = c("eng", "scot", "wale"), class = "factor"), 
                           edu = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                             1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                             1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                             1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
                                           .Label = c("x", "y", "z"), class = "factor"),
                           lungfunction = c(45L, 
                                            23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 23L, 25L, 45L, 
                                            70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 
                                            50L, 62L, 45L, 23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 
                                            23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 23L, 25L, 45L, 
                                            70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 
                                            50L, 62L, 45L, 23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 
                                            23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 
                                            90L, 50L, 62L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 25L, 45L, 
                                            70L, 69L, 90L),
                           ivdays = c(15L, 26L, 36L, 34L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 
                                      8L, 9L, 15L, 26L, 36L, 34L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 15L, 26L, 
                                      0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                      0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                      0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                      0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                      0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 36L, 34L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 
                                      9L, 36L, 34L, 2L, 4L, 5L),
                           no2_quintile = structure(c(1L, 
                                                      1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                      1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                      2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                      3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                      3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                      4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
                                                      5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L),
                                                    .Label = c("q1", "q2", 
                                                               "q3", "q4", "q5"), class = "factor")),
                      class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                          -100L))
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can't reproduce your code: `Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `across(c(estimate, conf.low, conf.high), exp)`.
Caused by error in `across()`:`?

Comment: By "display the estimated values" do you mean adding the numeric value of the parameter estimate to the plot?

Comment: @ Ben Bolker, yes

Comment: @ Ben Bolker, i added the picture

Comment: @ Quinten, many thanks for your prompt reply. the code is working fine at my end. not sure why you are having this error.

Comment: @Ben Bolker, i notice estimate value  in the  graph are different to values in ZINB model. is it possible for your cross your code please.